# Passing UTF-16 Japanese string from C# to Webbrowser control hosted in a form

Tags: javascript, c#, unicode, utf-16

This is work related.
We have a product which supports multiple languages, among them is Japanese.
The problem is that we have a module which is a browser control inside a windows form and when it gets the Japanese text from the C# side, an "Invalid characters" error shows in the log.

Basically the flow is:
C# has a JSON object that contains Japanese text.
Although the JSON appear to be invalid in text editor, it is a valid JSON when checking programmatically.

The object is being passed to the javascript from the C# using:

```
var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(msg);
            var msgB64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);

            if (msgB64 != "")
            {
                object[] init_args = { msgB64 };
                mForm.GetWebBrowser().Document.InvokeScript("dispatcher", init_args);
            }
```

Then on the javascript side the encoded text is being decoded as follows:

```
function dispatcher(message) {
  var decodedString = Base64.decode(message);
var result = "";
for (var i = 0; i < decodedString.length; i += 2) {
  result += String.fromCharCode(decodedString.charCodeAt(i) + (decodedString.charCodeAt(i + 1) << 8));
}
```

The reason for that is because this is IE running the JS in the background.

This code is just me trying to solve the Japanese issue , so I added the encode in Unicode and the odd code on the JS side.

But still, some strings break and I get "invalid characters" error for the JS side, probably when it tries to JSON.parse it.

Please no suggestion to change infrastructure/webview2 etc..

Thank you!

Comment: if the error is from javascript side, why you put only the C# code? Try to focus and debug your problem

Comment: I put both.. look again.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking a C# Unicode string, converting it into a byte array in UTF-16 format, base64-encoding those bytes into a Unicode string (that is holding characters in the ASCII range), passing that Unicode string to Javascript, and then base64-decoding that Unicode string into another Unicode string.

You are expecting the output of `Base64.decode()` to be a byte array in UTF-16 format.  However, you did not say which `Base64` library you are using on the Javascript side (as `Base64` is not a built-in class), but if it is anything like [this one](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html) then the base64-encoded bytes are expected to be in UTF-8 format, and the output of `Base64.decode()` is a normal Unicode `String` that has been UTF8-decoded, not a byte array in UTF-16 format, as you are expecting.

If that is actually the case in your situation, then try this instead:

```cs
var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
var msgB64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
mForm.GetWebBrowser().Document.InvokeScript("dispatcher", msgB64);
```

```js
function dispatcher(message) {
  var result = Base64.decode(message);
  // use result as-is ...
}
```

However, since `msgB64` on the C# side is a Unicode string, and `message` on the Javascript side is also a Unicode string, then you are already able to pass Unicode text as-is from C# to Javascript, so just get rid of the base64 encoding/decoding altogether, as you don't actually need it at all:

```cs
mForm.GetWebBrowser().Document.InvokeScript("dispatcher", msg);
```

```js
function dispatcher(message) {
  // use message as-is ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. To clarify, I was using "dankogai/js-base64".   How do I know the HTML/Javascript side knows that it's handling Unicode?  Is it the charset value? If so, what should I set it to (currently it's utf-8)?  Seconds question is about the C# "Text.Encoding".  Originally we added the encoding to UTF8 on the C# side because it solved issues with Cyrillic languages. Does the solution you suggested (removing the encoding altogether) work with Russian/Ukrainian languages?